# where does the drupal6 cck field default value stored in database?

Tags: 6, nodes

Is there a way to get the default value in a cck field (in drupal 6)?When I set the default value,the nodes created after that, are having this default value.(in database also ,table name is content_type_contenttypemachine).

Initially I set the default value as '1000' and later changed it to "4000" but when am trying to get the value from the content type table its retrieving the first value as "1000" and not the recent value "4000".

Is fetching the last record is the only way to get the latest default value I have set?

Thanks in advance,
cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to go directly into the database for that, you can use the [`content_field_instance_read()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!cck!includes!content.crud.inc/function/content_field_instance_read/6) function:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'content', 'includes/content.crud');
$definition = content_field_instance_read(array('field_name' => 'field_foo'));

// Your mileage may vary here, inspect $definition[0]['widget'] to see what you've got available.
$default = $definition[0]['widget']['default_value'][0]['value'];
```

If you're dead set on going into the database, the info is stored as a serialised PHP string in the `widget_settings` column of the `content_node_field_instance` table.